# cannot load such file -- guard/rspec/dsl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I was able to successfully install rspec-rails and guard-rspec. I am using windows so the version of rspec has to be old for it to succeed the installation.

```
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri

  gem 'postgresql'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8', :require => false #'2.8'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'ruby_dep', '1.4.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false#'4.2.'
end
```

I ran `rails g rspec:install` and spec-helper.rb was generated under spec. no rails-helper.rb though. I have .rspec file too.

I got the following after running `guard init rspec`

```
10:56:04 - INFO - Writing new Guardfile to C:/Users/nidaa_bugis/Documents/Ruby practices/workspace/Testing/Guardfile
10:56:05 - INFO - rspec guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
```

but when I run `bundle exec guard` I get this error

```
10:56:39 - INFO - Run 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows
10:56:39 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
> [#]
> [#] cannot load such file -- guard/rspec/dsl,
> [#] backtrace:
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
```

Anybody knows how to solve this issue and finally run guard and rspec on windows?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem but I have Ubuntu Linux, no idea about windows. 
I just update to the latest version, you can find it on the respective repository:
[guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec)
But it seems that this wasn't possible in your case.
In case you have Windows 10 you can use a [Linux beta environment](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

I hope that my first answer in Stackoverflow will still been useful for you and/or for somebody :).

Cheers!

Tonio